# postMessage once the window loads successfully

Tags: javascript, notifications, service-worker, service-worker-events

I am trying to implement following feature

User opens up a `page 1` on which there is a `button`. On clicking that `button` another window opens up but before that program checks whether the window is already open or not if it is already open than re-open the existing window or else open the new window.

While opening a window , I am passing some data to newly / existing open window using `postMessage`.

Now, the problem is when I am opening a window ( if it is ***NOT*** already open) then sometimes window is not able to receive the message sent by postMessage` hence I have used the setTimeout in following code.

However, this is not a reliable solution so I need a way where in newly open window receive the message each time.

Following is the code of `service worker`

```
let matchingClient = null;

    for (let i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
        const windowClient = windowClients[i];

        if (windowClient.url === urlToOpen) {


            matchingClient = windowClient;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (matchingClient) {


        // if window is already open then just focus on window 
        matchingClient.focus();
        // post the message
        channel.postMessage({action: event.action,information:event.notification.data ? event.notification.data.info : ""});

    } else {

        //if window is not open yet, then open a new window
        clients.openWindow(urlToOpen);

        //have used setTimeout because opening a window may take time , however this is just a workaround
        setTimeout(function(){      
            console.log("Delayed");
            //post the message
            channel.postMessage({action: event.action,information:event.notification.data ? event.notification.data.info : ""});

        },4000);


    }
});
```

Comment: You can send message from newly opened window to the parent to indicate that it is "ready" and only then post message with data or use MessageChannel to request some data from ServiceWorker and respond directly to it.

Comment: @wirher well, this approach leads to another issue. How would I send the message "Active" to the client once the service worker is `activated`?